# Readonly input focuses

Tags: javascript, forms, focus

Example: there are two input elements "old password" and "new password". When the second one focuses, a function is called to compare the value of "old password" and the actual old password. Thats all good, but when both inputs are set to "readonly = true" and the user clicks on the second input, the above mentioned function is called, although the user can not type into the input (focus fires on readonly input). I'm using the jQuery .focus() method.

One solution would be to check each time with an if statement(see bellow), but my question is, is there another method similair to .focus() in jQuery or in bare JS, which won't fire, when the input is set to readonly

```
if (!readonly) { ... }
```

Comment: css attribute `pointer-events:none` possibly? I admit I don't really understand what you're asking though

Comment: Keep some working code here

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the answers. I edited the question using an example, I hope it's clearer now